# Custom config files in spring-boot

Tags: java, configuration, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application which has an `application.yml` file in `src/main/resources`.

I need to override a value set in this file in a custom `application.yml` file stored in a custom directory

I have consulted these docs
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

I have tried adding `--spring.config.location=custom_directory_path` to the end of the command line when launching the app from the command line

I have tried creating an ENV variable called `spring.config.location` (however i cant do this because dot is not a valid bash name character

Interestingly when I remove the value from the main application.yml file and re-run the program it still maintains the value which was set these. could this mean it is getting it from a different location and this is taking precedence over the command line argument (it should not as the command line argument is supposed to take precedence over every other source) 
so far i have had no luck

any ideas

Comment: Use `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` instead.

Comment: is the use of capital letters the key?

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding . But no the upper case and use of _ instead of . ...

Comment: If you are using YAML file then shouldn't you be using `spring: \n \t config: \n \t location: custom_directory_path` where `\n` is New line, `\t` is Tab, can't format this in comments so I put `\n \t`